# Want to select data from each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to select data from each group(EID) which contain only Amanda and Dina in Involvement column.
This is my table data

```
EID Ename           EPrice  Involvement
1   Breakfast           60  Amanda
1   Breakfast           60  Dina
2   Dinner              50  Nick
2   Dinner              50  Dina
2   Dinner              50  Amanda
2   Dinner              50  Jessica
```

I want a result

```
EID Ename           EPrice  Involvement
1   Breakfast           60  Amanda
1   Breakfast           60  Dina
```

I don't want the result from EID=2 because it contains NICK AND JESSICA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where eid in
(
    select eid 
    from your_table
    group by eid
    having sum(case when involvement not in ('Amanda','Dina') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
)
and involvement in ('Amanda','Dina')
```

Comment: sorry I've edited my question. This answer is perfect according to the previous question. Please see my question again and help me.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Juergen. This is what i want

Comment: Mr.Juergen, why you use sum function this query? I'm I right because you have to filter the group which don't contain amanda and dina, because we have to use agg function with having?

Comment: I sum up the `involvement`s for neither `Amanda` nor `Dina`. This must be zero for the groups you like to select.